# Error while launching Eclipse installed via Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-16.04

I installed Eclipse through the Ubuntu Software Center of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and got the below error on opening.
My jdk version is 17:
openjdk 17-ea 2021-09-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17-ea+11-Ubuntu-116.042)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17-ea+11-Ubuntu-116.042, mixed mode, sharing)

Can anyone please help me solve it?

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOEnM.png)

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
    /usr/bin/java
    -Xms40m
    -Xmx384m
    -Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
    -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
    -jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
    -os linux
    -ws gtk
    -arch x86_64
    -showsplash /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_3.8.1.dist/splash.bmp
    -launcher /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse
    -name Eclipse
    --launcher.library     
  /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.dist/eclipse_1503.so
    -startup /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
    --launcher.overrideVmargs
    -exitdata 2b8011
    -vm /usr/bin/java
    -vmargs
    -Xms40m
    -Xmx384m
    -Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
   -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
   -jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
```

**EDIT 2**
[SCREENSHOT2][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGTr1.png

Comment: That is an extremely old version of Eclipse and won't run with Java 17. Install the current version directly from the official site https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Comment: Thank you for your response. Will do it and get back.

Comment: I tried it. Now it shows JVM terminated. Exit code = 127

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGTr1.png